# Jenkins Pipeline errors out accepting multiple values from a groovy method

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I'm trying to accept multiple values from a groovy method into a Jenkins pipeline and keep hitting Pipeline Workflow errors, any pointers as to what I'm doing wrong here is greatly appreciated.

```
(env.var1, env.var2, env.var3) = my_func()

def my_func(){
  def a =10
  def b =10
  def c =10
  return [a, b, c]
}
```

I get following error:

```
expecting ')', found ','  @(env.var1, env.var2, env.var3) = my_func()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using [Groovy's multiple assignment](http://groovy-lang.org/semantics.html#_multiple_assignment) feature incorrectly. It works when you assign a collection of values to a list of new variables. You can't use this type of assignment to assign values to an existing object. Your code also fails when executed in plain Groovy:

```
def env = [foo: 'bar']

(env.var1, env.var2, env.var3) = my_func()

println env

def my_func(){
  def a =10
  def b =10
  def c =10
  return [a,b,c]
}
```

Output:

```
1 compilation error:

expecting ')', found ',' at line: 3, column: 14
```

In Jenkins environment, `env` variable is represented not by a map, but by [`EnvActionImpl` object](https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-cps-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jenkinsci/plugins/workflow/cps/EnvActionImpl.java) which means it does not even support `plus()` or `putAll()` methods. It only overrides `getProperty()` and `setProperty()` methods, so you can access properties with `env.name` dot notation.

### Solution

The simplest solution to your problem is to use multiple assignment correctly and then set env variables from variables. Consider following example:

```
node {
    stage("A") {
        def (var1, var2, var3) = my_func()
        env.var1 = var1
        env.var2 = var2
        env.var3 = var3
    }

    stage("B") {
        println env.var1
    }
}

def my_func() {
  def a = 10
  def b = 10
  def c = 10
  return [a, b, c]
}
```

Keep in mind that `var1`, `var2` and `var3` variables cannot already exist in current scope, otherwise compiler will throw an exception.